# Is it possible to submit DIV elements (NOT Form) using jquery/ajax

Tags: html, upload, jquery

Is it possible to submit <strike>FORM</strike> DIV elements (NOT Form) using jquery/ajax?
I know of multiple was you can use jquery.form.js and jquery.upload.js. But they don't meet my requirements.

I have the following HTML within my *ASCX* control (within my *ASPX* master page that already has a **FORM** tag)

```
<div id="Div1">
    File: <input type="file" id="fileName"/><br/>
    Tags: <input type="text" id="fileTags"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit File"/>
</div>
```

My question is:
I want to **submit only the two elements** (fileName and fileTags) in this DIV and not the whole ASPX form.
Is there a jquery script/plugin that I can use to submit this DIV's element to the server without refreshing the page? e.g.

```
$("Div1").ajaxSubmit();
```

Without having to recreate the wheel.

Comment: What do you mean by "submit DIV elements"? Submit the markup? The content? Child content? Descendant Content?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to walk the HTML, and dynamically create an object to be submitted:

```
var obj = { filename: $('#filename').val(), fileTags: $('#fileTags').val() };
$.post('url.aspx', obj, myCallbackFunction);
```

That will send `obj` as a POST to your server. Your server side code can access the `fileTags` via `Request.Form["fileTags"]`

**However** I do not think that will work on a file upload control.

Comment: I think the OP is tying himself in knots and there is no way to do whatever it is he wants to do, but this should at least be educational

Comment: Agreed. I use what I wrote often enough, but never with a file upload. Maybe something like Flash or Silverlight might be a valid option?

Answer (score 0):

`<input> isn't even valid without a <form>`

Comment: If you read the question you will have noticed that it is in a MASTER PAGE that already has a FORM element

Comment: you realise that the contents of a slave page will be within the masters form?